# "No such file or directory" C++ header issue

Tags: c++, gcc, header-files

I'm working on a project that has [three cpp files and two header files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiY8B.png)

All my files are in the same folder.

I've been trying to link the header files with the cpp files for the past few days and I'm struggling so much with it.
Firstly, I tried to add the files in Build Options > Search directories > Compiler > Add
 [Image of my setting in Build options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faCc3.png)

I've ensured that my header files are typed out properly:

vectorfunc.h

```
#include <vector>
#ifndef VECTORFUNC_H_INCLUDED
#define VECTORFUNC_H_INCLUDED

//my vector functions declaration

#endif // VECTORFUNC_H_INCLUDED
```

vectorfunc.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include "vectorfunc.h"
#include <iostream>

//my function definitions
```

TrackKalman.h

```
#ifndef TRACKKALMAN_H_INCLUDED
#define TRACKKALMAN_H_INCLUDED

void TrackKalman();

#endif // TRACKKALMAN_H_INCLUDED
```

TrackKalman.cpp

```
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "vectorfunc.h"

//function definition of TrackKalman()
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include "TrackKalman.h"

//main function
```

Despite all this I still get the error in my compiler:

```
                                                              ||=== Build: Debug in RadarScanner (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 files\RadarScanner\TrackKalman.cpp -o obj\Debug\TrackKalman.o||No such file or directory|
 files\RadarScanner\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o              ||No such file or directory|
                                                              ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

I'm using the GNU GCC Compiler

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't seem to fix the issue and I definitely don't want to make the whole program in one file.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: It looks like your IDE tries to compile files that don't exist.

Comment: I think your problem is caused by the space in your path. There seems to be a space between CPP and files in your path. My advice is to never put spaces in paths you use for projects. Remember that in c++ many of the compilers run on the command line / shell and a space can mean a different argument. The solution to your problem may be putting quotes around the path in your picture or better yet get rid of the space in the path and avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the

```
 #include "TrackKalman.h”
```

As first line in TrackKalman.cpp